# Converting Junk characters to String

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

From the web service we are getting output as a junk string (ÇáŞØÑí ãä ÇáÊÃåá ÈÈÑÇÚÉ - arabic). What are the option available in java to convert the junk string to normal string for manipulation.

Comment: How do you read the output ?

Comment: The above junk text is the output parameter of the webservice and it is stored in a variable. The junk text in a variable needs to be converted to normal string for manipulation.

Comment: I know. But how do you get this value ? what type of reader you use ?

Comment: The junk is not in the file so didn't use any reader. Just used StringBuffer.

Comment: Could you post some code snippets ?

Comment: A web service can be inspected easily. Did the header indicate some charset? You might experiment with `s = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-6");` but better to know what is happening.

Comment: The assumption that the server is sending you "junk" and that not knowing what to do with it is no fault of yours is ... psychologically interesting.  Anyway, please read the [`character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) and update your question accordingly.